# Property is already defined error in wsdl2java

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java

I am trying to generate proxy classes from wsdl2java using cxf, but whenever I try I keep on getting below error:

> WSDLToJava Error: http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/shopping/Grou
>   pedItineraryResponse_v1-0-2.xsd [0,0]: Property "ValidatingCarrier" is already d
>   efined. Use <jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
>   http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/shopping/GroupedItineraryRespon
>   se_v1-0-2.xsd [0,0]: The following location is relevant to the above error

I tried to add binding file to wsdl2java.bat as I got info from one of the url like this:

```
<jaxws:bindings wsdlLocation="http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/shopping/BargainFinderMaxRQ_v1-8-2.wsdl" 
xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" 
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"> 


<jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema"> 
    <jaxb:globalBindings 
            jaxb:version="2.0"> 
        <xjc:simple />  
    </jaxb:globalBindings> 
</jaxws:bindings>
```

I am using third party wsdl url, so I don't have any control to change on the server side, I need to make changes only on command to successfuly generate proxy classes. Can someone kindly help me in this issue?

Comment: Are the URL's http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb and http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc working for you? Here they redirect me to an HTML page at Oracle and have been doing so for the past few hours.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `FareType` has both child element named `ValidatingCarrier` and attribute with the same name.

To work around this you should add field binding as suggested by error message. Example binding:

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
jaxb:version="2.1"
schemaLocation="http://webservices.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/shopping/GroupedItineraryResponse_v1-0-2.xsd">
    <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='FareType']/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='ValidatingCarrier']">
        <jaxb:property name="validatingCarrierInfo"></jaxb:property>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

With this binding I renamed `ValidatingCarrier` to `ValidatingCarrierInfo`.